# How to find a file name from the database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a list of files in my html where I have removed the directory `ImageFiles/` from the filename. So for example the file names look like below:

```
tulips.png
koala.png
jellyfish.png
```

Now if the user clicks on one of these file names, then I want to retrieve the file from the database, but in the database all files contain the directory `ImageFiles/` at the start of the file name. So in the database the files look like this below:

```
ImageFiles/tulips.png
ImageFiles/koala.png
ImageFiles/jellyfish.png
```

My question is simply how do I finish the WHERE clause in order to retrieve the correct file from the database? For example if I am looking for the file `tulips.png`, how can I get the query to be able to find `ImageFiles/tulips.png` and only this file from the database?

Below is the mysqli query:

```
$getimage = $_GET['filename'];

    $imagequery = "SELECT ImageFile FROM Image WHERE (ImageFile = ?)";

            if (!$imagestmt = $mysqli->prepare($imagequery)) {
            // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }


    // Bind parameter for statement
    $imagestmt->bind_param("s", $getimage);

    // Execute the statement
    $imagestmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend the directory name to the `$getimage` variable:

```
$getimage = 'ImageFiles/' . $_GET['filename'];
```

Comment: Can I quickly ask, to display the image of the file do I just do this: `<img alt="Loading" id="tempImg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="$getimage">`?

Comment: @user1881090 - You have to wrap it in php tags, and echo it: `src="<?php echo $getimage; ?>"`. In the future, ask such questions in a new question thread.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to save from adding another question, but thanks for the quick reply and for your answer :)